# Selection with pandas multiIndexed dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing, multi-index

I have a multiIndexed dataframe that looks like this:

```
df.head():
```

[image]

How can I select all of the rows where the first index == "particular school name" and all of second indices, where the Month column == "Jan"?

I haven't worked with multiIndexed dataframes before, I can select all rows where Month == "Jan" like this:

```
df[df['Month'] == 'Jan']
```

but this gives me all of the schools.  I've been playing with it, but haven't been able to add indexing for just one school. So how does this work?

**Edit:** Ok so this works: `df[df['Month'] == 'Mar'].loc["School Name"]`, but is there a more idiomatic way this is done or would this be the standard way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
print (df.query('ilevel_0 == "School Name" and Month == "Jan"'))
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['School Name','Agona','another'],
                   'B':[0,1,2],
                   'Month':['Jan', 'Jan', 'Feb']}).set_index(['A','B'])
df.index.names = [None, None]
print (df)
              Month
School Name 0   Jan
Agona       1   Jan
another     2   Feb

print (df.query('ilevel_0 == "School Name" and Month == "Jan"'))
              Month
School Name 0   Jan

print (df.query('ilevel_0 == "School Name" & Month == "Jan"'))
              Month
School Name 0   Jan
```

Solution with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = (df.index.get_level_values(0) == 'School Name') & (df['Month'] == 'Jan')
print (df[mask])
              Month
School Name 0   Jan
```

EDIT:

For working with variable use `@`:

```
var = 'School Name'
print (df.query('ilevel_0 == @var & Month == "Jan"'))
              Month
School Name 0   Jan
```

Comment: If the `School Name` is a variable, should I do it like this, `df.query('ilevel_0 == "'+schools[2]+'" and Month == "Feb"')` or better to use boolean indexing, or the way I added in my edit?

Comment: I think `query` is much faster espacially in larger df, in my opinion here is more readable use `query` instead `boolean indexing`. But works both solutions.

Comment: And for variable is possible use `@`, see last edit. [Docs for multiindex query syntax](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#multiindex-query-syntax).